# How can I save the positions of the icons in GNOME 2?

Tags: gnome

Using Centos 6.5 with GNOME 2.

Puting the notebook on an external monitor always randomly puts the icons to different places. It would be a great thing if I can just set the position of them back with a script/click.

**My question:** How can I save the positions of the icons on the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I think [fbdesk](http://fluxbox.sourceforge.net/fbdesk/) is your friend. Though, it is designed for fluxbox but it should work for Gnome 2 too. ( I haven't tried it yet )

Once installed, you just have to execute this binary to re-arrange the desktop icons as and when required.